# VSCode - disable three dots for "Could not find a declaration file for module"

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to prevent these three dots from showing up without adding the corresponding type files?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings.json and paste

```
"javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false
```